# How to solve Add reference to microlib error in Visual Studio 2017 UWP?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-universal

Hi I have developed a UWP app which was targeting to version 14393, but recently Microsoft released new SDK so I changed target to 15063 from the following screen
[image]

After, doing this. I am now getting assembly reference error on every line of my code. The error is shown in the following screenshot. Can you please suggest how to resolve this error? I tried to search but everyone was adding some reference in web.config file which is not available for Windows 10 UWP project.[image]

Comment: Have you tried compiling the app? This looks like unresolved NuGet dependencies..

Comment: Clean and rebuild will resolve your issue.